# Wordpress metabox drop down list isn't saving

Tags: php, wordpress, save, metadata

I have 2 custom post types named `clients` and `casestudies`. I'm trying to build a meta box on the `clients` post type that will have a drop down list featuring the titles of all posts from the `casestudies` post type. This will end up with a page displaying the featured image from the `clients` post type, then hyperlink off to the relevant `casestudies` post if a selection is made from the drop down list.

I have followed this tutorial to get a meta box put together: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-custom-wordpress-writemeta-boxes--wp-20336

This is the meta box code I have in my functions.php file:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'cd_meta_box_add' );
function cd_meta_box_add()
{
    add_meta_box( 'my-meta-box-id', 'My First Meta Box', 'cd_meta_box_cb', 'clients', 'side', 'default' );
}

function cd_meta_box_cb( $post )
{
$values = get_post_custom( $post->ID );
$selected = isset( $values['my_meta_box_select'] ) ? esc_attr( $values['my_meta_box_select'][0] ) : ”;
    ?>     
    <p>
        <label for="my_meta_box_select">Select which case study this logo will link to when it is clicked:<br /><br /></label>
        <select name="my_meta_box_select" id="my_meta_box_select" style="width:100%;">
            <option value="No case study">No case study</option>
                <?php
                $casestudies = array( 'post_type' => 'casestudies', 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'asc', );
                $casestudiesloop = new WP_Query( $casestudies );
                while ( $casestudiesloop->have_posts() ) : $casestudiesloop->the_post();
                    ?> <option value="<?php the_title(); ?>" <?php selected( $selected, $casestudies['the_title'] ); ?> ><?php the_title(); ?></option>
            <?php
                endwhile;
                    ?>
        </select>
    </p>
    <?php    
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'cd_meta_box_save' );
function cd_meta_box_save( $post_id )
{
    if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;

    if( !isset( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'], 'my_meta_box_nonce' ) ) return;

    if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) return;

    if( isset( $_POST['my_meta_box_select'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_meta_box_select', esc_attr( $_POST['my_meta_box_select'] ) );
}
```

The meta box displays correctly on the correct post type, but when I update the post it won't save the data.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have nonce hidden field. Save function would return nothing.

```
<input type="hidden" name="meta_box_nonce" id="meta_box_nonce" value="<?php echo wp_create_nonce( 'my_meta_box_nonce' ); ?>" />
```

**UPDATE:**

So your `cd_meta_box_cb` function would be

```
<?php
    function cd_meta_box_cb( $post )
    {
        $values = get_post_custom( $post->ID );
        $selected = isset( $values['my_meta_box_select'] ) ? esc_attr( $values['my_meta_box_select'][0] ) : ”;
        ?>
        <p>
            <label for="my_meta_box_select">Select which case study this logo will link to when it is clicked:<br /><br /></label>
            <select name="my_meta_box_select" id="my_meta_box_select" style="width:100%;">
                <option value="No case study">No case study</option>
                    <?php
                    $casestudies = array( 'post_type' => 'casestudies', 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'asc', );
                    $casestudiesloop = new WP_Query( $casestudies );
                    while ( $casestudiesloop->have_posts() ) : $casestudiesloop->the_post();
                        ?> <option value="<?php the_title(); ?>" <?php selected( $selected, $casestudies['the_title'] ); ?> ><?php the_title(); ?></option>
                <?php
                    endwhile;
                        ?>
            </select>
        </p>
        <input type="hidden" name="meta_box_nonce" id="meta_box_nonce" value="<?php echo wp_create_nonce( 'my_meta_box_nonce' ); ?>" />
        <?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: Didn't seem to help. I've checked the `wp_metadata` and there isn't a `my_meta_box_select` ID in there, so it isn't saving anything.

Comment: OK so it's now saving into the `wp_metadata` table, but when loading a post from the `clients` post type, the drop down doesn't select the current value. Any ideas on that? I did have issues getting the `<?php selected( $selected, $casestudies['the_title'] ); ?> ><?php the_title(); ?>` to display correctly.

Comment: Instead of `<?php selected( $selected, $casestudies['the_title'] ); ?>` use `<?php selected( $selected, get_the_title() ); ?>`